# Edges in a DFS forest

Tags: depth-first-search

I came across the following question.

---

The DFS forest generated by DFS on a DAG will have the following edges

---

A)BACK EDGES B)CROSS EDGES C)FORWARD EDGES D)NONE OF THESE

---

---

### The answer was options B and C.Please explain how C is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a DAG, multiple nodes can point to the same node, thus resulting in a cross edge or a forward edge in the DFS forest. Back edges in a DFS forest would indicate loops in a graph, so a DFS forest of a DAG never has any back edges.

It's just the basic functionality of DFS, really.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search